# C++ CRTP constructor of derived class

Tags: c++, constructor, crtp

I have some questions about the CRTP. Let's say I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>

// interface

template<class Imp>
class Interface{
  public:
    inline void print(void){
      std::cout<<"value: ";
      return asImp().print();
    }
  private:
    typedef Imp Implementation;
    inline Implementation& asImp(void){return static_cast<Implementation&>(*this);}
};

// add
class Add:public Interface<Add>{
  public:
    inline void print(void){std::cout<<value<<std::endl;++value;}
  private:
    int value;
};

// main
int main(void){
  Interface<Add> foo;
  foo.print();
  foo.print();
}
```

The output is

```
value: 0
value: 1
```

Therefore the variable `value` seems to be constructed as 0 by the default constructor. But I don't understand where and when this constructor is called since no object of the derived class is created.

Moreover, let's suppose that I want create value with a different starting value, how can I achieve that using this design pattern? 
Obviously I could create an `init()` method in the derived class which is called in the constructor of the base class but it wouldn't work for a type which hasn't a default constructor.

Finally, is it possible to forward some arguments pass to the constructor of the base class to the constructor of the derived class?

Comment: I think what's going on here is that you're `static_cast`ing your `foo` to an `Add`, which does no runtime check. It's then interpreting the data at the place where it would find `value` as though it were part of the original structure (`Interface<Add>`). It just happens to be 0.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, you are accessing the part of `Add` that is not initialized (you cast a base pointer to a derived pointer, but only the base part is constructed, then access the derived part). For example, I get junk under `g++`, `value:-466819072` and `value: -466819071`

Comment: Ok. So is there a way to have variables stored in the derived class? Or the only solution is to have it in the base class?

Comment: You want `Add fooinst;`. Then, `Interface<Add> &foo = fooinst;`.

Comment: @jxh for what I understand, in this designed pattern, the derived class shouldn't be created (it is like a policy).

Comment: That would be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your source code, you yourself name the base class as `Interface`. In the object oriented sense, you do not create instances of an `Interface`, but instances of classes that derive from the `Interface`. Your code in main erroneously instantiates an `Interface` rather than the class that derived from it. You can fix this by forcing `Interface` with properties that make it impossible to instantiate.  E.g.:

```
template<class Imp>
class Interface {
    //...
protected:
    Interface () {} // not accessible except by derived
};
```

Unlike regular polymorphism, you are not really expected to pass `Interface` objects around. The `Interface` provides enforcement of a particular interface by providing the expected methods, and those that derive from the `Interface` must adopt the expectations of that interface. Your example is a little contrived because the `Interface` is actually just dispatching to the same named method in the derived. But, a better example is one where the `Interface` provides an implementation using properties it expects the derived type to provide.

In the example below, we see that `Worker` inherits the interface of `WorkerInterface`. But, because of the expectations of `WorkerInterface`, it is required to implement `perform()` and `wait()`. While a pure interface enforces this requirement with pure virtual methods, CRTP enforces this with template expansion.

```
template <typename JOB>
class WorkerInterface {
public:
    void work () { while (job().wait()) job().perform(); }
private:
    JOB & job () { return *static_cast<JOB *>(this); }
protected:
    WorkerInterface () {}
};

class Worker : public WorkerInterface<Worker>
{
    friend class WorkerInterface<Worker>;
    int state_;
    void perform () { std::cout << "Worker: " << __func__ << '\n'; }
    bool wait () { return state_--; }
public:
    Worker () : state_(1) {}
};

int main ()
{
    Worker w;
    w.work();
}
```

Now, any class that derives from `WorkerInterface` will be provided a `work()` method that will do the "right" thing as long as the derived class provides suitable implementations of `wait()` and `perform()`.

Answer (score 2):

You're **NOT** creating a derived object in fact.

You're creating a base class object and casting it to a reference of the derived type, but the underlying object is still a base class one and thus **it's wrong**.

`static_cast` always succeeds, but will raise undefined-behavior if you don't cast to the right type while `dynamic_cast` returns a NULL pointer if you casted it wrong.

-> Try it live here, you might or might not get garbage values: http://ideone.com/dP3jjU

The other initialization question should be straightforward once you've addressed the above.

More on this: [Should static_cast<Derived *>(Base pointer) give compile time error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2469013/1938163)

Comment: Therefore, since no derived object is created, why does the variable value exists? I would expect an error.

Comment: @MarcoAgnese you casted the pointer, so `C++` has the memory layout for a derived object, but the latter is not-initialized. It is the same as saying `(Derived*) p`, where `p` is just some pointer to some memory. Sintactically you will be able to write `p->member`, but of course it will make no sense.

Comment: @MarcoAgnese [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means that anything could happen. You're likely accessing memory owned by your own process (thus no access violation) but reading garbage, uninitialized, unset, values.

Comment: @Marco A. Yes got it, for this reason I was asking if there is a proper way to construct variables in the derived class. But since, it is never constructed, I think that the answer is NO. Therefore, is there a design pattern to have static polyphormism and variables in the derived class?

Comment: One of the points of [CRTP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/262254/1938163) is to be able to do static polymorphism and know the type of the derived object at compile-time. If you create a derived object you can simply initialize the variables you need there, unless I'm missing your point

Comment: I will try to do an example. Let's say that I want to create 2 derived classes: AddOne and AddTwo. I want that an object Interface<AddOne> has value constructed to be 0 while if I create an object Interface<AddTwo> the value is constructed as 1. Is there a way? I suppose that there isn't if I understood correctly your explanation

Comment: You're missing one point: **you create derived objects**, not base ones. Take a look at here: http://ideone.com/n9Ol72