# If I cast the this pointer of a base class to the derived type, is it safe and well defind?

Tags: c++, crtp

If I have a template base class that takes the type of the derived class, is safe to cast the this pointer of this base class to the type of the derived class?

Consider this code, where the base class `A` casts the this pointer to a template parameter (`Derived`). It also checks if the provided type is actually derived from this class. It obviously works (here), but is it well defined?

```
#include <iostream>

class D;

template<typename Derived, typename T>
class A
{
public:
    Derived *thisToDerived() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of< A<Derived, T>, Derived>::value, "not");
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
private:
    T m;
};


class D : public A<D, int>
{
private:
    double d;
    float f;
};


int main() {
    D d;
    std::cout<<"this:    "<<&d<<"\nderived: "<<d.thisToDerived();
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2469013/1896169

Comment: Also related, almost answers this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4173254/1896169

Comment: To put it simply, yes this is safe

Comment: `is_base_of< A<Derived, T>, D>` seems to be wrong. If you restrict potential derived classes to D alone, you don't need to define any templates. Perhaps you meant `is_base_of< A<Derived, T>, Derived>`.

Comment: yes, this was what i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have a template base class that takes the type of the derived class, is safe to cast the `this` pointer of this base class to the type of the derived class?
>   ...
>   It obviously works (here), but is it well defined?

Yes, it's safe and is well defined. It's actually a well known and commonly used pattern (see [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)) and aka *Static Polymorphism*.

Examples of usage:

- [**Microsoft ATL**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ax346b7.aspx)
- Alexei Andrescou's [**Loki library**](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/)

---

```
Derived *thisToDerived() {
    // Your static_assert is superfluos
    // static_assert(std::is_base_of< A<Derived, T>, Derived>::value, "not");
    return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // Already guarantees that Derived is inherited from A
}
```

Comment: Pedantic mode on: CRTP is an idiom, not a pattern.

Comment: @skypjack Well, nitpicking back: At least the _P_ in CRTP stands for _Pattern_ ;-)